# Snippet regex: match arbitrary number of groups and transform to CamelCase

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, camelcasing, vscode-snippets

In a Visual Studio Code Snippet I'm writing I want to convert a snake case string to camel case.

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets) I know that the syntax is

```
'${' var '/' regex '/' (format | text)+ '/' options '}'
```

so I've come up with this :

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([a-z])([a-z]*)_+([a-z])([a-z]*)_+/${1:/upcase}$2${3:/upcase}$4/}
```

This code however works only for strings with 2 elements (for exemple "carrot_cake") while I would like to process strings with arbitrary number of elements ("blueberry_pie_with_a_cup_of_coffee").

I guess that some kind of recursion is needed in `'regex'` and `'format'`, but I have no idea of what to do.

How does one match arbitrary number of pattern occurrences?

Comment: Your not going to get an _arbitrary_ number of replacements. But, you could set up a regex to get say 20 or less. For example, this does 5 segments: `([a-z])([a-z]*)(?:_+([a-z])([a-z]*)(?:_+([a-z])([a-z]*)(?:_+([a-z])([a-z]*)(?:_+([a-z])([a-z]*))?)?)?)?` Adjust replacement as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

What does `?:...?` do?

Comment: `(?: anything )` is a non-capture group, it's known as a _cluster_ group. Adding a `?` after it makes it optional.

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE**

vscode v1.75 is adding a `Transform to Camel Case` command, so rather than a snippet transformation you could select the result and trigger that command.  Just FYI.

---

**UPDATE**

vscode v1.58 added a `/camelcase` transform.  which makes your use case very easy now.

`"${1/(.)(.*)/${1:/upcase}${2:/camelcase}/}"`

to go from `blueberry_pie_with_a_cup_of_coffee` to `BlueberryPieWithACupOfCoffee`

---

`"${1/(.*)/${1:/camelcase}/}"` // just capture the whole thing

to go from `blueberry_pie_with_a_cup_of_coffee` to `blueberryPieWithACupOfCoffee`

vscode's implementation uses this regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so anything other than those characters will be seen as separators - and the following "word" will be capitalized.

---

---

Previous answer::

To transform an arbitrary number of "_" separated words into CamelCase try:

**EDIT**: In October, 2018 (but not yet added to snippet grammar documentation as of February, 2020) vscode added the `/pascalcase` transform, see [commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0604b4f7c48af64fc22644ae02d4b367848c0a3f).  I have modified the code below to use the `/pascalcase` transform.  It only works for the `some_file => SomeFile` type of CamelCase though.

But it works with many characters as separators, these all work:

```
blueberry_pie_with_a_cup_of_coffee
blueberry-pie-with-a-cup-of-coffee
blueberry-pie-with_a-cup-of_coffee
blueberry-pie-with.a-cup-of.coffee
blueberry*pie-with.a*cup-of.coffee
blueberry*pie@with.a*cup1of.coffee
blueberry*pie@with.a*cup1of.coffee
```

---

```
"camelCase": {
    "prefix": "_cc",
    "body": [
            // "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([a-z]*)_+([a-z]*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:/capitalize}/g}"

            "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}"
        ],
        "description": "Transform to camel case"
    },
```

`carrot_cake.txt` ->     `CarrotCake`

`blueberry_pie_with_a_cup_of_coffee.js` ->   `BlueberryPieWithACupOfCoffee`

[I assume `CamelCase` is the form you want, there are others, such as `camelCase`.]

For **`camelCase`**:

```
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([a-z]*)[-@_.*0-9]+([a-z]*)/$1${2:/capitalize}/g}"
```

put your desired list of separators in the `[-@_.*0-9]+` part.  The `+` quantifier allows you to use `carrot--cake` for example - multiple separators
between words.  Thanks to the other answer for using the `[list the separators]` part of the regex.

Note that the "g" flag at the end is doing most of that work for you in getting however many matches there are beyond the two explicitly captured.

I left the capture groups as `([a-z]*)` as you had them.  You may want to use `([A-Za-z0-9]*)` for more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you! camelcase is not working it is putting comma between each word. example: submit-page.ts   it is doing "submit,page"

Comment: It isn't doing that for me and I tested it on your example `submit-page.ts`.  There really is no way for it to be adding a `,` anywhere.  You would have to post a new question with a gif showing it not working and your precise snippet - I think you have added a stray `,` somewhere it shouldn't be (like inside the quotes?).  Same with the other answer - it isn't adding a `,` anywhere as well.

Answer (score 3):

### vs code snippet transform to **camelCase**:

```
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": [
        "${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([-_.])(.*)/${1:/downcase}${2}${4:/pascalcase}/}}"
    ]
}
```

wrapper is `${1:}`,

inner is `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([-_.])(.*)/${1:/downcase}${2}${4:/pascalcase}/}`

wrapper is `${}`

inner is `TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([_\\W])(.*)/${1:/downcase}${2}${4:/pascalcase}/`

string is `TM_FILENAME_BASE`

#### -------------------------------------------------------**split**

part 1 is `/^(.)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([-_.])(.*)`

part 1.1 is `^(.)`  →  `$1`, first **character**

part 1.2 is `([a-zA-Z0-9]*)`  →  `$2`

part 1.3 is `([_\\W])`  →  `$3`, **delimiter**, ignore

part 1.4 is `(.*)`  →  `$4`

#### -------------------------------------------------------**replace**

part 2 is `/${1:/downcase}${2}${4:/pascalcase}/`

part 2.1 `${1:/downcase}` → lowercase

part 2.2 `${2}` → normal

part 2.3 `${4:/pascalcase}`

---

for-bar.service.js  →  fooBarService

---

Not strong enough, but enough.

Comment: This is adding comma between the words not working.

Comment: @RupeshKumarTiwari other variable place need add index number. See my blog for details: https://blog.csdn.net/xianghongai/article/details/105763724