# VS Code: How to convert snippet placeholder to uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In VS Code, the docs for creating [user defined snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) mentions some [Grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) which includes options for `/upcase`, `/downcase`, and `/capitalize`, but I can't figure out how to use it.

I'm using the latest version of VS Code: `Version 1.25.0` on Mac.

It seems like this snippet should convert the value of the placeholder to uppercase and to lowercase after typing it and hitting tab, but it doesn’t:

```
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": "${1} -> ${1:/upcase} ${1:/downcase}"
},
```

### Flow and Expected Result

1. type `test`
2. hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to get the snippet.
3. type `Asdf` to result in:

   ```
   Asdf -> Asdf Asdf
   ```
4. hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to get expected result of:

   ```
   Asdf -> ASDF asdf
   ```

### Current Result

```
asdf -> asdf asdf
```

Comment: This is now built in to VS Code, as of [version 1.47](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47#_case-changing-in-regex-replace).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    // "body": "${1} -> ${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/} > ${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}"
    // simpler version below works too
    "body": "${1} -> ${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase} ${1:/downcase}/}"
}
```

You need to hit *Tab* to apply the transformation.

Comment: Follow up question: Do you know if there is a way to convert a camelCASE string to SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE string using snippets?

Comment: Found this, but the examples don't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelcase

Comment: The input from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelCase is very different from your input on the present question.  SO I am not sure what you mean by "the examples don't work."?

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes, the examples work as it. When I attempt to use the example to update a placeholder, I can't get them to work. Created a new question to clarify another need I have for a snippet:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277998/vs-code-how-to-convert-snippet-placeholder-from-camelcase-to-screaming-snake-ca

Comment: I've added a 50 point bounty to my related question… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51277998/vs-code-how-to-convert-snippet-placeholder-from-camelcase-to-screaming-snake-ca

Comment: Would have made a lot more sense if they just made a JS API for snippets instead of a DSL like this...

Comment: Not working at all for me, it doesn't change the case, not even after I hit `Tab`.

Comment: Okay, turns out some extension is borking the case change...don't have the problem when I run `code --disable-extensions` ‍♂️

Comment: Sometimes also you can inadvertently select a different intellisense option when you hit `Tab` rather than this snippet.  I wouldn't use `test` as a real prefix - it was what the OP had just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Mark is it also possible to split a camelcase string into lowercase parts, e.g. "testCase" to "test case"?

Comment: @icaptan Yes it is very easy but you should post a question on it.  Longer code is ugly in a comment.

Comment: In this example `<$2${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}>` pressing tab will downcase $1 but weirdly enough, the cursor is then *after* $1 transfomed and not *before* as you would expect to fill up "$2", did I miss something?

Comment: @EricBurel I have seen that before, where a tabstop right next to another doesn't work.  A simple `"$2$1"` also fails.  You can reverse the tabstops and it works or insert a space between them.  So it's a bug.

Comment: It indeed works if I do "$2-$1" for instance

Answer (score 17):

Kind of solution:

```
  "test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": "$1 ${1/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}  ->  ${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}  ->  ${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}"
  }
```

result:

```
asdF ASDF  ->  asdf  ->  AsdF
```

Comment: If a user has updated VS Code, is this necessary to run?

Comment: My VS Code version is 1.53.0. You need first to save this snippet to snippets file then you can use it as a usual snippet.

Comment: A link to the doc maybe ?

Comment: Finally found the doc: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/snippet/snippet.md#placeholder-transform

Answer (score 3):

*For reference:*

The integer in the EBNF docs refers to a RegExp group not to a tabstop reference so should work:

```
"test": {
    "prefix": "test",
    "body": "${1} -> ${1/(Asdf)/${1:/upcase}/} ${1/(Asdf)/${1:/downcase}/}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It works for me, but I've accepted the other answer as it works with any string, not just the sample text of "Asdf".

Answer (score 1):

Doc is here.

You can use capitalize, camelcase, pascalcase, selection, clipboard, random and date also.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/snippet/browser/snippet.md