# VSCode Code-Snippets transform: downcase and capitalize at the same time

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have this:

```
${1/([A-Z]*)(?:_)([A-Z]+)*/${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase}/g}
```

How to make use `downcase` and `capitalize` on the same (2) group?

```
${1/([A-Z]*)(?:_)([A-Z]+)*/${1:/downcase}${2:/downcase/capitalize}/g}
```

I want to tansform `ZXC_ASD` to `zxcAsd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
"camelCaseSnail": {
"scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "log",
    "body": "${1/([A-Z]*)(?:_)(?:([A-Z])([A-Z]+))*/${1:/downcase}${2:/capitalize}${3:/downcase}/g}"
}
```

[image]

Basically, I've changed the second capture group `([A-Z]+)*` to a non-capture group that has two inner capture groups `(?:([A-Z])([A-Z]+))*`, a single letter for camel-case and the rest, which I refer in the replace/transform part: `/downcase}${2:/capitalize}${3:/downcase}/`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently coming to vscode v1.58 is a `/camelcase` modifier.  So your case is as easy as

```
"${1/(.*)/${1:/camelcase}/}"
```

[image: camelCase transform example]

Tested in the Insiders Build.  See [Add a camelCase transform for Snippet variables](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ea132060dd8c71baa6b2f77e46287710b888bb01).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228186/836330 for another example.

---

Old answer:

Using the undocumented (see [Snippet regex: match arbitrary number of groups and transform to CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelcase/51228186#51228186)) `/pascalcase` transform, it is quite easy:

`"${1/([A-Z]*)(?:_)([A-Z]+)*/${1:/downcase}${2:/pascalcase}/g}"`

as the `/pascalcase` will do both the `/capitalize` and the `/downcase` at once.