# When creating a VSCode snippet, how can I transform a variable to title-case (like TitleCase)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholdertransform

My aim is to automatically set the class name within the context of the snippet being inserted. VSCode does not natively support class or method names, but it does support the file name.

My file names closely mimic the class name:

`foo-bar.ts` for `class FooBar`.

Here is my current code snippet wherein I can transform `"foo-bar"` to `"Foo-bar"` using the native "capitalize" grammar provided by VSCode. 
`TM_FILENAME_BASE` is a native variable which extracts the filename without the extension:

```
"My Snippet": {
    "scope": "typescript",
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
        "${1}() {",
        "\treturn this.get(${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}.FIELD.${3});",
        "}",
        "",
        "$0"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a function wrapper for a model's attribute."
}
```

I'd like to transform "foo-bar" to "FooBar".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
  "My Snippet": {
    "scope": "typescript",
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
      "${1}() {",

      // "\treturn this.get(${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([a-z]*)-*([a-z]*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:/capitalize}/g}.FIELD.${3});",

      "\treturn this.get(${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}.FIELD.${3});",

      "}",
      "",
      "$0"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a function wrapper for a model's attribute."
  }
```

**EDIT** : In October, 2018 the `\pascalcase` transform was added to vscode - see 
[commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/0604b4f7c48af64fc22644ae02d4b367848c0a3f), but not yet added to the documentation (as of the date of this edit).  I have added the much simpler transform above which accomplishes the PascalCase transform.

Demo added, uses the clipboard after the first filename case (`test-bed-snippets.xxx`) just to make the various possibilities easy to demonstrate.

[image: pascalCase snippet demo]

See also [snippet transform to CamelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelcase)

Comment: Hey, thanks! Would your code work for a single word file? ```foo``` -> ```Foo```?

Comment: It does now, I just changed the hyphen from + to * so it is optional.

Comment: Really appreciate this!

Comment: @Israel It work for any number of file names like `foo-bar-longer-name` or `foo_bar_longer_longer_name` or any mix of hyphens and underscores in the same filename.  Any file extension.

Comment: Good lord, this just cost me hours in trying to figure it out because the documentation is still missing. Thanks for this...

Comment: However, it doesn't work with a camelCase. Trying to convert "camelCase" would result in "Camelcase" where the second "c" is changed to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it might be useful to supplement Mark's excellent answer with another example.

In my case, I wanted to take a name - as selected text - and convert it to Swift code that would instantiate a new class passing in variables name and email address.

So for example I select `John Smith` as first name, last name and convert to:

`let johnSmith = User(name: "John Smith", email: "john.smith@foorbar.com")`

Code snippet for this would be as follows:

```
"User": {
        "prefix": "u",
        "body": [
            "\tlet ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/([a-zA-Z]*) *([a-zA-Z]*)/${1:/downcase}$2/} = User(name: \"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\", email: \"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/([a-zA-Z]*) *([a-zA-Z]*)/${1:/downcase}.${2:/downcase}/}@foobar.com\")\n",
        ],
        "description": "Create User with name and email"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`TM_FILENAME_BASE`: The filename of the current document without its extensions.

`${1:/upcase}`: change to uppercase.

`g`: used to perform the replacement globally.

```
"My Snippet": {
    "scope": "typescript",
    "prefix": "snippet",
    "body": [
        "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(?:^|-|_|\\.)(\\w)/${1:/upcase}/g}"
    ],
    "description": "Creates a function wrapper for a model's attribute."
}
```

[UserDefinedSnippetsVariablesSRC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables)