# VSCode snippet, transform lowercase string delimited by underscores into CamelCase?

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code, camelcasing, vscode-snippets

I'm writing a custom snippet in **VSCode** to help me define custom class methods easily. I need to be able to enter a string 'formatted_like_this' and have the regex transform that string in certain places so that it becomes 'FormattedLikeThis'?

The custom snippet to be written in php.json: (see 'NEED HELP WITH REGEX HERE' for the spot where I am struggling)

```
"New Custom Class Method For Variable": {
    "prefix": "contcmpffv",
    "body": [
        "protected $$1 = null;",
        "public function get${NEED HELP WITH REGEX HERE}()",
        "{",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Controller Class Method Public Function For Variable"
}
```

My desired workflow:
1. type contcmpffv
2. press enter when prompted with matching snippet
2. snippet prompt's me for $1

Desired Output (inputting "test_input_string" when prompted for $1):

```
protected $test_input_string = null;
public function getTestInputString()
{
    *cursor resolves here (due to $0)*
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about visual studio custom snippets, but in javascript something like this would work: `('formatted_like_this').split('_').map((el)=>el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1)).join('')`. I'm not sure if it helps, but maybe you can write something similar in visual studio?

Comment: @Berci Unfortunately I cannot use JavaScript string functions for this purpose, but thank you for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"body": [
    "protected $$1 = null;",
    "public function get${1/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}()",
    "{",
    "\t$0",
    "}"
],
```

It uses the undocumented `pascalcase` transform - which has been around for some time.  It does all the work for you in this case.

This is what you could use if there was no `pascalcase`:

```
"public function get${1/([^_]*)_*/${1:/capitalize}/g}()",
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark, this worked perfectly! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: brilliant second option. That definitely further's my understanding of Regex expression reading. Any idea what the Regex would be for [ this_camel_case => thisCamelCase ] (first word begins lcase, all other words begin ucase)?

Comment: See my answer here for camelCase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104851/snippet-regex-match-arbitrary-number-of-groups-and-transform-to-camelcase/51228186#51228186

Comment: how about if you need to get rid of underscores '_'?

Comment: @LelandReardon You'll have to explain your starting text, the `pascalcase` transform does get rid of the underscores.  Do you mean get rid of underscores and do nothing else?