# Multiple transforms in VS Code snippets

Tags: vscode-snippets

To streamline adding a text input in a React component in VS Code, I have created a snippet that performs multiple transforms.

- I want the `id` of the element to use hyphens (e.g. "user-name", as is normal for CSS
- I want the `name` of the element to use underscores, to match the field names in a database (e.g. "user_name")
- I want the name of the event listener to be in camelCase (e.g. "updateUserName")

In many cases, I should be able to simply type the `id`, and then press the `TAB` key a few times to apply transforms to the various attribute values. However, I also want to be able to customize each value, so I have applied additional tab stops that allow me to edit the values for `name` and `onChange`.

Here's the working snippet:

```
"input:text": {
    "prefix": "i:t",
    "body": "<input\n  type=\"text\"\n  id=\"${1:user-name}\"\n  name=\"${2:${1/-/_/g}}\" // ${4:${2/_(.)/${1:/upcase}/g}}\n  onChange={${3:update${5:${4/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}}}}\n/>",
    "description": "Text Input"
  },
```

If you add this snippet to your `javascriptreact.json` file, you can then type `i:t` in a React script, then press `TAB` a few times, to get this result**:

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="user-name"
  name="user_name" // userName
  onChange={updateUserName}
/>
```

I feel that I have had to cheat, though.

On the line for `name`, you can see a comment: `// userName`. To create my default listener name, I need to transform `user_name` (with underscores) into `UserName` (with a capital letter *both* at the beginning *and* to replace any letter after an underscore (that is, matching the regex `/_(.)/`).

I haven't found a way of doing this in one step, so I have used an intermediary step ($4), which creates the commented string.

My question then: **How could I alter the transforms used for the `onChange` entry, so that I can avoid this intermediate step?**

** You can, of course, type in your own values for `id`, `name` and the `onChange` listener.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my own question : )

1. Capture the first character and also all the rest of the string
2. Use the `/capitalize/` transform on the first character and the `/camelCase/` transform on the rest.

---

```
"input:text": {  
  "prefix": "i:t",  
  "body": "<input\n  type=\"text\"\n  id=\"${1:user-name}\"\n  name=\"${2:${1/-/_/g}}\"\n  value={${3:$2}}\n  onChange={${4:update${5:${2/(.)(.*)/${1:/upcase}${2:/camelcase}/}}}}\n/>",  
  "description": "Text input"  
},
```

Here's [where the answer comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228186/1927589). Kudos to @Mark.